# Adobe CQ: Copy node from one CQ instance to another using crx/de

Tags: aem, jcr, crx

I am working with Adobe CQ and testing some code that works on one instance and does not on another. The jcr nodes I am testing the same code with are different and I am able to debug only the working instance(my local one). I need to copy the node from failing CQ instance to another using crx/de or any other tool to test both instances with the same data. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You copy repository contents from one instance to other using the package manager

**<host>:<port number>/crx/packmgr/index.jsp** .

1. Create a new package with the nodes you want to package as the
   filters.
2. Build the package
3. download it
4. Upload it to the required
   instance
5. Install the package

detailed documentation of this feature is available here https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/package_manager.html